# Topical disinfectant safe for dogs

Tags: medicines, injury

Our cocker spaniel has a little sore patch between two of her toes (caused by abrasion from something that got stuck between them). It doesn't seem vet-worthy but we would like to put a topical disinfectant on it to help ensure it heals.

There is conflicting advice on-line as to which disinfectants are safe or unsafe for dogs.

Does anyone know for sure some that are OK? Advice would be much appreciated.

(Photo as requested - not that easy to see as it is right down between the toes - we only found it when she started intermitently hopping about)[image: Sore between the dogs toes]

There was a bit of something like a hard mud stuck on the hair so it hadn't come out (and I suppose was too far in for her to pull it out herself). Once we cut it out I wouldn't have noticed that she was disfavouring that leg if I hadn't been looking very hard, and 24 hours later she was absolutely normal.

Comment: While it might prove irrelevant, it is still better if you post a picture of the affected area - not just the paw, but the patch itself, if possible.

Comment: Photo added as requested. Thanks.